# Executing C# Script in Java

Tags: java, c#, scripting

I have a little C# script that I created that gets some system information. I was wondering if there is a way to use the C# script without creating an exe and running the exe from it. I have it setup so it will pull information from executing the exe but I would like something a little more generic and doesn't rely so much on the exe but on the C# script itself.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://www.ikvm.net/.

IKVM.NET is an implementation of Java for Mono and the Microsoft .NET Framework. It includes the following components:

```
A Java Virtual Machine implemented in .NET
A .NET implementation of the Java class libraries
Tools that enable Java and .NET interoperability
```

Comment: I just found a post about this exact thing. Looking into it right now.

Comment: hope you find what you are looking for.